# Is there a way to increase thickness on JavaFX ProgressIndicator component?

Tags: css, javafx, styles

I can't find a css property to increase the ProgressIndicator bar thickness.
Or a library that let me do something like that.

Now it looks like that:

[image: Actual javaFX progressindicator]

Comment: have you tried    progressBar.setSize(new Dimension(x, y));

Comment: if using eclipse try advanced properties change the `size` property of the progress bar

Comment: Can you show how you're creating the indicator in your image? The vanilla indicator in JavaFX does not look like that.

Comment: @PaddyPopeye setSize is not a method in NetBeans

Comment: @Slaw is from Gluon Theme.

Comment: Try `.progress-indicator:indeterminate > .spinner { -fx-stroke-width: <size>; }`.